# window.onload function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, onload

I've noticed some bug in `window.onload` function. (Maybe it's my wrong) 
The problem is when I used following simple function, it worked on all browsers but Chrome.

```
var name=$("#name");
window.onload = function(){
    name.fadeIn(500);
};
```

Then just for interest, tried this one too:

```
var name;
window.onload = function(){
    name=$("#name");
    name.fadeIn(500);
};
```

In all above cases, Chrome's dev tools gave me this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fadeIn'
```

I've resolved this error with following code.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var name=$("#name");
    name.fadeIn(500);
};
```

But now want some explanation, why didn't work first 2 piece of code?

Comment: Don't know about the second example, but that first block of code may be requesting an element that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I cached `name` before working with it, `var name=$("#name");` and again, on all other browsers it worked only CHROME gave error

Comment: What do you mean by caching? I'm not a JQuery expert, but if `$()` functions are essentially `getElementById()` functions, the `name` element may not have loaded into the DOM yet. Why it is exclusive to chrome is a puzzler though. Do you put your scripts at the bottom of the page by the way?

Comment: yes the code is at the bottom. I told you that THIS SCRIPT WORKED ON ALL OTHER BROWSERS. imo there is no syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this might be down to a global variable called name. If you call name something different, name1, it works in chrome.http://jsfiddle.net/R2PuZ/1/

Comment: OMG)). I didn't even think about this. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, I played around with it a bit... assigning a value to a global variable in Safari will acknowledge that it's an element, but it won't have any (or at least some) properties (such as innerHTML). Works in Firefox though. Very strange.

Comment: yeah, one of those things that makes you burn the midnight oil:) It's very interesting that name is set to "result", which in the jsfiddle seems to come from the name of  the iframe where the result is displayed. Still playing with it..

Comment: Yep, if I open the src of the result iframe at http://fiddle.jshell.net/R2PuZ/1/show/ name is no longer set, however, it is still defined.